# Find feature in GeoJson based on Lat/Lng coordinates

Tags: c#, asp.net, geolocation, geojson

I have a GeoJson dataset consisting of 20-30 features with a mix of MultiPolygon and likewise.
I then have a set of coordinates and I want to;

1. Lookup and see wheather the supplied coordinates are within the bounds of some of the features in my GeoJson dataset
2. If they are, then return that feature with the properties of that specific feature.

All this is to be done in C# (WebApi)

Any suggestion as to how I would go about this?

Comment: GDAL is a lib that enables spatial queries and operations. Alternativly use NetTopologySuite. Anyway your question is *veeeeery* broad and this task is pretty complex. What have you tried already yourself? What is the spatial coordinate-system  (CRS) of your data?